# how to reduce .py code using for loop and conditions using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to simple question here:

1. First Question How to read a `txt` or any `file` without declaring the name of the file, I will make a ceratin path for example in `C:\Users\mahmoud\PycharmProjects\text_files` this path folder contains all the `text` files i want to convert So I want to create something like a `for` loop that looping in the path and convert all this types of files to `csv` to `excel`.

2.How to reduce the code as the below, as this code related to the first question.

```
import pandas as pd

dataf_gsm_car_txt = 'gsmcarrier_mnm.txt'
dataf_gsm_rel_txt = 'gsmrelation_mnm.txt'

class push_all_to_csv(object):
    def push_gsmcarrier(self):
        dataf_gsm_car_txt_df = pd.read_csv(dataf_gsm_car_txt, sep=';')
        dataf_gsm_car_df_column_index = list(dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.columns)
        dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.drop(columns=dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
        dataf_gsm_car_df_column_index = dict(zip(list(dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.columns), dataf_gsm_car_df_column_index))
        dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.rename(columns=dataf_gsm_car_df_column_index, inplace=True)
        dataf_gsm_car_txt_df.to_excel('gsmcarrier_mnm.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)

    def push_gsmrelation(self):
        dataf_gsm_txt_df = pd.read_csv(dataf_gsm_rel_txt, sep=';')
        dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index = list(dataf_gsm_txt_df.columns)
        dataf_gsm_txt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dataf_gsm_txt_df.drop(columns=dataf_gsm_txt_df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
        dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index = dict(zip(list(dataf_gsm_txt_df.columns), dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index))
        dataf_gsm_txt_df.rename(columns=dataf_gsm_rel_df_column_index, inplace=True)
        dataf_gsm_txt_df.to_excel('gsmrelation_mnm.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)

    def push_umtscarrier(self):
        dataf_umts_car_txt = 'umtscarrier_mnm.txt'
        dataf_umts_car_txt_df = pd.read_csv(dataf_umts_car_txt, sep=';')
        dataf_umts_car_df_column_index = list(dataf_umts_car_txt_df.columns)
        dataf_umts_car_txt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dataf_umts_car_txt_df.drop(columns=dataf_umts_car_txt_df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
        dataf_umts_car_df_column_index = dict(zip(list(dataf_umts_car_txt_df.columns), dataf_umts_car_df_column_index))
        dataf_umts_car_txt_df.rename(columns=dataf_umts_car_df_column_index, inplace=True)
        dataf_umts_car_txt_df.to_excel('umtscarrier_mnm.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)

    def push_gsmrelation(self):
        dataf_umts_rel_txt = 'umtsrelation_mnm.txt'
        dataf_umts_txt_df = pd.read_csv(dataf_umts_rel_txt, sep=';')
        dataf_umts_rel_df_column_index = list(dataf_umts_txt_df.columns)
        dataf_umts_txt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dataf_umts_txt_df.drop(columns=dataf_umts_txt_df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
        dataf_umts_rel_df_column_index = dict(zip(list(dataf_umts_txt_df.columns), dataf_umts_rel_df_column_index))
        dataf_umts_txt_df.rename(columns=dataf_umts_rel_df_column_index, inplace=True)
        dataf_umts_txt_df.to_csv('umtsrelation_mnm.csv')

def get_push_all_to_csv():
    return push_all_to_csv()
```

I just need to structure code some thing like this using `pandas` function like `to_csv`, 'to_excel', `where`, `isin`.... alot of funtions and some of `sql` queries as a support as the design of code structure as I imagine should be like the below:

```
database_connection/
│
├── .conncetion.py
to_sql/
│
├── .file_tosql_1.py
├── .file1_tosql_.py
to_csv/
├── .file1_tosql_.py
├── .file1_tosql_.py
assets/
Main_App.py
```

As I found a way to reduce `methods` calling through the below code:

```
#Method that call in the methods which in the class
def call_all(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    for name in dir(obj):
        attribute = getattr(obj, name)
        if ismethod(attribute):
            attribute(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any suggestion?

## Edited

```
def clean(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    df = df.reset_index().drop(columns=df.columns[-1])
    new_cols = dict(zip(list(df.columns), cols))
    df = df.rename(columns=new_cols)
    new_file_path = path.split(".")[:-1].append(".xlsx")
    df.to_csv(path, index=False)

def main():
    path = r"C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\ToolUpdated\data_feed"
    pathPat = os.path.join(path, "*.txt")
    all_file_name = glob.glob(pathPat)

    for file_path in all_file_name:
        print (file_path)
        clean(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Edited 2:

```
path = r"C:\\Users\\haroo501\\PycharmProjects\\ToolUpdated\\data_feed"
pathPat = os.path.join(path,"*.txt")
all_file_name = glob.glob(pathPat)
for file_path in all_file_name:
    with open(file_path) as currentFile:
        pd.read_csv(currentFile, delimiter = "\t")
        print(file_path)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/ToolUpdated/txt_to_csv/convert_to_csv.py", line 64, in <module>
    pd.read_csv(currentFile, delimiter = "\t")
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 532, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1

```
import os
import glob
path = r"D:\txtFiles"
pathPat = os.path.join(path,"*.txt")
all_file_name = glob.glob(pathPat)
for fileName in all_file_name:
    with open(fileName) as currentFile:
        #do somthing with the file
```

Comment: how can I use file name then I used something like `fileName.to_csv()` but doen't work

Comment: if it is a csv use df = pd.read_csv(currentFile)  if you get not wanted "," or "\t" use pd.read_csv(currentFile, delimiter = "\t")

Comment: do you have any idea how to solve this error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\haroo501\\PycharmProjects\\ToolUpdated\\data_feed'`

Comment: several possibilities, start with closing the file before running the script

Comment: it's already closed and it's just a path folder.... I think I have to make permission or someting

Comment: try writing the clean csv to a different folder then the original, or at least change their name

Comment: I tried and it's still not working :( as i find this error `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`, please could you check Edited post in Edited 2

Comment: one of the files is empty? or not csv, put a try except around the read_csv

Comment: yes it's right but I also find the same problem I backed to my old code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `glob` library to access the file as mentioned by [trigonom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12829545/trigonom) above. And use a single function to iterate over all the files and save them back.

**UPDATE**: I was using `path.split(".")[:-1]` to create an .xlsx filename from the original name, however this would return list of strings and hence caused the errors. You can replace the extension to the file using `str.replace`.

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

def clean(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    df = df.reset_index().drop(columns=df.columns[-1])
    new_cols = dict(zip(list(df.columns), cols))
    df = df.rename(columns=new_cols)

    # new change here
    new_file_path = path.replace(".txt", ".xlsx")
    print (new_file_path)
    df.to_excel(path, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

def main():
    path = r"D:\txtFiles"
    pathPat = os.path.join(path, "*.txt")
    all_file_name = glob.glob(pathPat)

    for file_path in all_file_name:
        print (file_path)
        clean(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    main()
```

Comment: do you have any idea about this error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` :)

Comment: I tried to use `append` instead the `+` but it doen't work

Comment: could you check my edit please the code didn't convert anything after using `append` as also `new_file_path` variable is not declared

Comment: I added a workaround to the error here. This would work as expected.

Comment: hah now I found this :( `ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'txt'`

Comment: Check your dataframe `df` using `df.head()`. I am suspecting that `pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')` isnt reading the file. If so, change your `sep` value.